# php suhosin alerts

Tags: php, alert, suhosin

I use suhosin. I get the following alerts.

`ALERT-SIMULATION - tried to register forbidden variable '_REQUEST' through GET variables (attacker

ALERT-SIMULATION - tried to register forbidden variable '_REQUEST[option]' through GET variables (attacker

ALERT-SIMULATION - tried to register forbidden variable '_REQUEST[Itemid]' through GET variables (attacker

ALERT-SIMULATION - tried to register forbidden variable 'GLOBALS' through GET variables (attacker`

Are they real attackers? If not, how to set suhosin configuration to ignore these alert?

Answer (score 3):

Those are not necessarily "attacks," but rather tests/prodding of your site to determine if they (the potential attacker) can inject code though register_globals being enabled.

The uri's used to produce those errors are as follows

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?_REQUEST=someValue
http://www.example.com/index.php?_REQUEST[option]=someValue
http://www.example.com/index.php?_REQUEST[ItemId]=someValue
http://www.example.com/index.php?GLOBALS=someValue
```

Do you have `register_globals` set to `on`?

That IP traces to ATL: http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/

Comment: Thanks, the IP is actually our own server. To remove these alerts, how to do suhosin configuration? What is `register_globals`?

Comment: Yikes to "What is register_globals" ... read my post on what register globals is and how it can be exploited: http://dan.doezema.com/2010/04/php-register-globals-overview after that find out what you need to configure here: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html

Comment: I like the post. It is very useful. However, I still do not figure out how to set in suhosin configuration. I do not see any setting related with the alerts. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error repeatedly ... spamming my syslog

> 3 22:32:01 **REDACTED SERVER NAME** suhosin[16290]: ALERT-SIMULATION -
>   Include filename
>   ('phar:///**REDACTED**/lib/cron.phar/Cron/CronExpression.php') is an
>   URL that is not allowed (attacker '127.0.0.1', file
>   '**REDACTED**/lib/cron.phar', line 12)

... but register_globals are definitely off ... so what's the issue?

Comment: Solved my own issue, suhosin is not set up to recognize phar as a type http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/suhosin-phar.htm

$ emacs /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini
.. add the following line:
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar